# Ruby/Rails counting objects in scope with calculated column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I can't figure out how to count objects in a scope appropriately.

For this example, let's assume products ("skus") had a lat and lng, and so do users.

I have a find_by_sql example that works:

```
  def self.with_max_distance(user, distance)
    Sku.find_by_sql(
    <<-eos
      SELECT *,
      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(#{user.lat}) ) * cos( radians( skus.lat ) )
      * cos( radians(skus.lng) - radians(#{user.lng})) + sin(radians(#{user.lat}))
      * sin( radians(skus.lat)))) AS distance
      FROM skus
      HAVING distance < #{distance}
    eos
    )
  end
```

I was able to get the following scope to work partially:

```
  scope :scope_with_max_distance, lambda { |user, distance|
    { :select => "skus.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(#{user.lat}) ) * cos( radians( skus.lat ) ) * cos( radians(skus.lng) - radians(#{user.lng})) + sin(radians(#{user.lat})) * sin( radians(skus.lat)))) AS distance",
      :having => "distance < #{distance}"
    }
  }
```

The scope appears to get the objects correctly, and although I haven't tested it extensively, it appears to work if I chain it with my other scopes.

However, I am unable to `count()` the objects, which is really annoying. I know I can use `length()`, but the fact that it doesn't work with count leaves me wondering if there's a better way to do this.

```
1.9.3p125 :048 > Sku.scope_with_max_distance(User.first, 50).limit(10).count
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM `skus` HAVING distance < 50 LIMIT 10) subquery_for_count 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause': SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM `skus`  HAVING distance < 50 LIMIT 10) subquery_for_count
```

I'd really appreciate any advice or ideas - I've tried many different approaches but haven't been able to find one that works completely. Please let me know if the issue needs more clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` will replace your `select` with just the simple elements it needs to build a count as efficiently as it can.  It will not check other constraints to ensure that the SQL is valid.  You can replace the `distance` alias in `having` with the formula you would be selecting to get around this problem.  Also, I recommend that you replace `having` with `where` to avoid implicit grouping that is not database portable:

```
scope :scope_with_max_distance, lambda { |user, distance|
  distance_formula = "(3959 * acos( cos( radians(#{user.lat}) ) * cos( radians( skus.lat ) ) * cos( radians(skus.lng) - radians(#{user.lng})) + sin(radians(#{user.lat})) * sin( radians(skus.lat))))"
  { :select => "skus.*, #{distance_formula} AS distance",
    :where => "#{distance_formula} < #{distance}"
  }
}
```

One last thing, you are calling `count` after `limit(10)` which would mean that count will never be greater than 10.  That's not inherently wrong, but I'm not sure that it's what you meant to do.

Comment: Makes total sense - I should have thought of that myself >_<. Thanks!